# Find sperator in field

Tags: ee2, ee3, custom-fields

Is there anyway to output entry data from a particular field, find the separator and output HTML based on that separator?

Example:

```
Postcode Field for Entry Outputs: LL21, LL22, LL33, LL44, LL46
```

But I want to find the comma and replace with an opening and closing

```
So the result would be: LL21</span> <span>LL22</span> <span>LL33</span> <span>LL44</span> <span>LL46
```

I would hard code the first and final span.

Is it possible EE2 and EE3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wonderful EE utility called [**Streeng**](https://github.com/caddis/streeng) to do this (and lots of other things).

`Streeng` performs a broad variety of manipulations on the tag outputs, including stripping out some or all of the `<html>` tags within it, and performing substitutions.  You could use these features to achieve what you are describing.

With `Streeng` installed, to get a version of the tag output with `,` replaced by `</span><span>` you would need to enclose the tag as follows:

`{exp:streeng 
  find="," 
  replace="</span><span>"}
    {your_tag_goes_here}
{/exp:streeng}`

HTH

Comment: Thank you for that! Just seen that available for ee3 too! Amazing!